# The script should be exected inside a X (graphical) session?

Tags: terminal, x11, osx

CONTEXT:
I git cloned fluxion and it downloaded without issue but when I go to run fluxion this message appears...

The script should be exected inside a X (graphical) session ?

And i Have know idea what it means. I'm not even sure if fluxion is even able to be run on Mac. Or maybe their is a simpler way to install fluxion on Mac.

I'm Running the latest version of Mac OSX at the time of this posting.
Thanks For Any Help

Answer (score 1):

Install XQuartz from [here](https://www.xquartz.org/). You should be good to go on the graphical end.

---

What is XQuartz?

"The XQuartz project is an open-source effort to develop a version of the X.Org X Window System that runs on OS X. Together with supporting libraries and applications, it forms the X11.app that Apple shipped with OS X versions 10.5 through 10.7." (XQuartz, www.xquartz.org/index.html.)